# Missing required key 'Bucket' in params

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to deploy a simple lambda function to aws but I get the error **Missing required key 'Bucket' in params**.
The user I have created has full Lambda, S3, Cloudformation and Cloudwatch access.

**JS**

'use strict';

```
module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      input: event,
    }),
  };

  callback(null, response);

  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // callback(null, { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event });
};
```

**YAML**

```
service: lambda-demo

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
```

Comment: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2341 some comments here. There several issues like this as well

Comment: I came across this error when I had too many s3 buckets, try removing a bucket and re-deploy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleting the stack in console and deploying stack again usually helps.

If it does not help try deploying stack with a new name (if using Serverless framework change name after 'service:' ).

Discussed [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2341).

Comment: Even though this answer got downvoted it was the fix for my case.

Answer (score 7):

Most often I have encountered this error when IAM user permissions have been changed between runs of "sls deploy" or are incorrect to begin with.

Best course of action is to go to AWS console -> CloudFormation and check the CloudFormation event logs to see what's going on. If the logs show error in permissions, fix permissions, delete the stack Serverless created from the console and run "sls deploy" again.

Comment: I just did all of that and still I get the error. Really frustrated with this one because there is not much info on this problem.

Comment: So there are no errors in the CloudFormation events?

Comment: Late reply, but after deleting the stack and deploying again, everything worked.

Comment: Same here. After deleting the stack everything worked.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks!