# I want to upload to aws s3 bucket, but my code is showing this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload to aws s3 bucket with this code, but the file as required from the code is showing undefined, can anybody help?

```
 app.post("/news_feed", async (req, res, next) => {
            const ID = "...";
            const SECRET = "...";
            const BUCKET_NAME = "iconpathbucket";

          const s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
               acessKeyId: ID,
               secretAcessKey: SECRET,
               Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
          });

               var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

               busboy.on("finish", () => {
               console.log("upload finished");

              const file = req.body.image;
              console.log(file);

            const params = {
                 Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
                 Key: file.name,
                 Body: file.data,
              };
              
            if (req.session.user_id) {
                s3bucket.upload(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                     console.log(err);
                } else {
                     console.log("This is the uploaded image", data);
                }
              });
            }
          });
        });
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting `undefined`? I see you also have a typo there `secretAcessKey` – should be `secretAccessKey` and also `acessKeyId` – should be `accessKeyId`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). Which will handle the request and upload the file/image to S3.

Example Code:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: './public/data/uploads/' })
app.post('/news-feeds', upload.single('uploaded_file'), function (req, res) {
   // req.file is the name of your file in the form, here 'uploaded_file'
   // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any 
   console.log(req.file, req.body)
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much.... I've done this, but I'm getting a new error that says "Missing required key 'Bucket' in params" while my params look like this   const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Body: fileStream,
    Key: file.filename 
  }

Comment: @AfolabiOpeyemi Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724886/missing-required-key-bucket-in-params